# how to set border onMouseOver event of javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to set border of 1px solid lightblue color for a  through javascript.. i hv written d follwng code....

```
function changeImage1(id){
document.getElementById(id).style.border="1px solid lightblue";
}
```

bt its not working.... i m using IE to test this... help me out....

Comment: It must have to do with how your calling your `changeImage1()` onmouseover because what you've got will change the border of an element with passed in id.

Comment: Do you have to support IE6? If not, you can simply do this using CSS, e.g. `#id:hover { border: 1px solid lightblue }`. And next time, please don't use these abbreviations like "hv" and "d follwng", it's hard to understand your question and there's no space limit here, this is not Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Better would be

```
<style type="text/css">
.normal {border: 1px solid black}
.lb { border: 1px solid lightblue }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(obj,on) {
  obj.className=(on)?'lb':'normal';
}
</script>
<a onmouseover="toggle(this,1)" onmouseout="toggle(this,0)" class="normal">Here</a>
<hr />
<a onmouseover="toggle(document.getElementById('s1'),1)" onmouseout="toggle(document.getElementById('s1'),0)" >Here</a>
<span id="s1">Or here</span>
```